# GIT How to view history of turnins

Tags: git, lookup, revision

I would like to see the history of changes for a file in GIT revision tool.
Also the date when turnin was done,who made the change and any related turnin comments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git - how do I view the change history of a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/git-how-do-i-view-the-change-history-of-a-file)

Comment: "turnin" is not a term that is used by anyone as far as I know. I think you mean "commit"?

Comment: People, we don't need to downvote a question just because it's a duplicate.  Pointing to the duplicate and closing the question is sufficient...if the other question is really a duplicate.  Plus, the other question is from nearly three years ago.  It's quite possible that Git has evolved to have other ways to do something after three years have passed.

Answer (score 1):

You mean log?

```
git log $FILENAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `whatchanged`:

```
git whatchanged myfile.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for who did what to that file, you could also use `git blame file.cpp`
doc : http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html

But if you're looking for the full commit history of that file, use `git log`
doc : http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log