# git diff renamed file

Tags: git, diff, rename

I have a file `a.txt`.

```
cat a.txt
> hello
```

The contents of `a.txt` is "hello".

I make a commit.

```
git add a.txt
git commit -m "first commit"
```

I then move `a.txt` into a `test` dir.

```
mkdir test
mv a.txt test
```

I then make my second commit.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "second commit"
```

Finally, I edit `a.txt` to say "goodbye" instead.

```
cat a.txt
> goodbye
```

I make my last commit.

```
git add a.txt
git commit -m "final commit"
```

Now here is my question:

How do I diff the contents of `a.txt` between my last commit and my first commit?

I've tried:
 `git diff HEAD^^..HEAD -M a.txt`, but that didn't work.  `git log --follow a.txt` properly detects the rename, but I can't find an equivalent for `git diff`.  Is there one?

Comment: I suppose it would be the same if you did a 'git mv a.txt test'? IE you just renamed the file instead of moving it into a subdirectory.

Comment: Related: an answer I just wrote: sometimes you need to leave off the file path to get it to track renamed files: [How to manually view the change history of a file graphically in `meld`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74965393/4561887)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The issue with the difference between `HEAD^^` and `HEAD` is that you have an `a.txt` in both commits, so just considering those two commits (which is what diff does), there is no rename, there is a copy and a change.

To detect copies, you can use `-C`:

```
git diff -C HEAD^^ HEAD
```

Result:

```
index ce01362..dd7e1c6 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-hello
+goodbye
diff --git a/a.txt b/test/a.txt
similarity index 100%
copy from a.txt
copy to test/a.txt
```

Incidentally, if you restrict your diff to just one path (as you do in `git diff HEAD^^ HEAD a.txt` you aren't ever going to see the renames or copies because you've excluded the everything apart from a single path and renames or copies - by definition - involve two paths.

Comment: Lets say the commit contained multiple file changes.  How would I narrow it down to a diff of a single file?

Comment: @KenHirakawa use `-- <old-path> <new-path>` ... see my answer.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to show the details of a commit where the file was renamed, but it was just showing me that a file was deleted and a file was added... I ran `git show -C [commit]` and it recognized the file rename and showed me the diff between the files.  Perfect.

Answer (score 110):

To diff across a rename of a specific file, use `-M -- <old-path> <new-path>` (`-C` also works).

So if you both renamed *and* changed a file in the last commit, you can see the changes with:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD -M -- a.txt test/a.txt
```

This produces:

```
diff --git a/a.txt b/test/a.txt
similarity index 55%
rename from a.txt
rename to test/a.txt
index 3f855b5..949dd15 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/test/a.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 // a.txt

-hello
+goodbye
```

(`// a.txt` lines added to help git detect the rename)

---

**If git isn't detecting the rename,** you can specify a low similarity threshold with `-M[=n]`, say 1%:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD -M01 -- a.txt test/a.txt
```

From [the git diff docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> **-M[<n>]
>   --find-renames[=<n>]**
>
> Detect renames. If `n` is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions
>   compared to the file's size). For example, `-M90%` means Git should
>   consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file
>   hasn't changed. Without a `%` sign, the number is to be read as a
>   fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., `-M5` becomes 0.5, and
>   is thus the same as `-M50%`. Similarly, `-M05` is the same as `-M5%`. To
>   limit detection to exact renames, use `-M100%`. The default similarity
>   index is 50%.

Comment: ...Of course, also works when the change and rename are in separate commits as in the original example: `git diff HEAD^^ HEAD -M -- a.txt test/a.txt`

Comment: Only when the contents of the files are close enough for diff to come up with a similarity index. Using both options (-M and -C) is showing the diff to /dev/null an from /dev/null in a file that was renamed and  has changed entirely (including indent wise), it doesn't even catch it when ignoring whitespace.

Answer (score 69):

You can also do:

`git diff rev1:file1 rev2:file2`

which, for your example, would be

`git diff HEAD^^:./a.txt HEAD:./test/a.txt`

Note the explicit `./` -- this format otherwise assumes the paths to be relative to the root of the repo.  (If you're in the root of the repo, you can of course omit that.)

This doesn't depend on the rename detection at all, as the user is explicitly stating exactly what to compare.  (Therefore, it also comes in handy in some other circumstances, such as comparing files between different svn branches in a git-svn environment.)

Comment: Oooh, this is nice!

Comment: For a rename with additional file changes brought in via a merge this is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: What @LaneRettig said.  Odd, because `git diff dev` correctly shows the limited changes, but all the rename detection suggestions fail and show the whole file as new.  So this answer works, just means you have to account for the rename manually.

Comment: When comparing to files from the same revision, I use `--no-index`, and I was having trouble with comparing files from different revisions because I kept using `--no-index`. So don't be like me, don't use `--no-index` in this command when comparing files from different revisions.

Answer (score 3):

If your rename commit is staged but not committed yet, you can use:

```
git diff --cached -M -- file.txt renamed_file.txt
```