# Very long-historied file in Git repo suddenly has blank log and is invisible to "git status"

Tags: git, version-control

I have a very, very old file in my Git repo that's had numerous commits to it. By chance, I wanted to compare it to a previous revision but I found that `git diff 5.0 Data/schema.sql` simply returned no output.

I knew this was wrong, so I ran `git log Data/schema.sql`. Again: no output!

I thought this could be a gitignore problem, so I completely removed my `.gitignore` file - no change. I even tried `git config --global --get-all core.excludesfile` and `git config --system --get-all core.excludesfile` - both returned no output.

I tried manually adding it with `git add`. There was no error message, but the file is not mentioned at all in `git status` - git is acting as if I told it to ignore the file, and on top of that, seems to have made its history inaccessible.

What on earth could be going on? This makes me nervous - this one file's history is not a big deal on its own, but I'm worried that something could be wrong/corupt with my repo as a whole.

What could cause this behavior and how can I fix it? I'm running the latest git (1.8.3.1) on Mac OS X (installed via Homebrew). Other files in the `Data` directory work as expected, and no other files in the repo exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Poking in the dark here, but is it possible the file ain't readable by the git user? (a chmod issue basically)

Comment: No, unfortunately they have the same owner and mode as other files that work fine.

Comment: did you try actually changing the file and then running `git status`?

Comment: Another shot in the dark: is it possible that file has been renamed? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7759392/6309): `git diff -C 5.0 Data/schema.sql`

Comment: The file is located in a submodule and your are in the directory of the top module ?

Comment: Ok. @Chronial's suggestion helped (thanks!). I made a change to the file and ran "git status". I saw that there was a change listed for "data/schema.sql" (lowercase "d"). And "git diff 5.0 data/schema.sql" even works. But the directory has a capital D in my local filesystem. So the problem appears to be this: git thinks that the directory is lowercase and my filesystem thinks it starts with a capital. This is a much more benign problem - still, how do I resolve that?

Comment: Although I never set this specifically, the Git config variable `ignorecase` is set to true. The default is false. Maybe this is causing the problem?

Comment: yes, it is :). Set it to false, then `git status` should say that `data` has been renamed to `Data`. And maybe some others. You can either fix that manually or run `git reset --hard` (but only if you have no uncommited changes!)

Comment: Thanks! If you want to make your comment an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments it looks like this might be a problem with upper/lowercase. Set `ignorecase` to false and either fix the name manually or reset the repo with `git reset --hard` (only if you have no uncommited changes).