# How can I get git to show me changes on an individual renamed file

Tags: git, file-rename

If I do

```
git difftool -y --find-renames master
```

I get diffs of any file with the original version on the branch, so if I've renamed 'a' to 'b' and changed it, I get the differences between the current 'b' and the original 'a'. But if, instead, I do

```
git difftool -y --find-renames master b
```

it gets compared with /dev/null. This is quite confusing.

Is there any way to get git diff to do what I expect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git diff renamed file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759193/git-diff-renamed-file)

Comment: no, because in that question and answer it's assumed you know the file is renamed and from what. That's not always the case.

Comment: Did you read the answer?  I believe it does answer your question.  The short form: no.  When you specify a path, you need to specify both (the original and the new path) or you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes I did and no it doesn't - it explains how to do what I want if you know what you want. it's not so helpful if you don't know what you want. I did check that question before i posted this one

Answer (score 2):

You can always be explicit about your comparison,

```
$ git diff master:a b
```

The `-M` (find-renames) and the `-C` are heuristics, and in your case you know that it was `a` that was explicitly renamed to `b`.

If `a` and `b` are not known in advance you can leverage your first command to get a list of suggestions first, followed by an excursion into the file histories:

```
$ git diff --find-renames --name-only master
```

invoking `log --follow` on every suspected rename:

```
$ git log --follow <renamed file>
```

Comment: I don't always know that. I happen to know in the example given, obviously. But it's not always the case - especially if someone else has renamed the file in another commit.