# Get commit log about only 1 folder

Tags: git, file, logging, commit

What I want to do is get a commit log of all the changes pertaining only to 1 folder in a repository. How, if at all, is this possible?

Comment: Found the answer here. Should've done more research.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git log --all -- some/path
```

Added for completeness. You may want to use "find copies" and "find copies harder" first to see if you want to add another path in case this path was renamed or copied at some point in the history.