# View a file's history in Magit?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

[View the change history of a file using Git versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning) talks about other ways of viewing history of a file in Git.

Can it be done in Emacs Magit?

Comment: Looks like this answer is part of what you're looking for https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7683/16879

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Since magit 2.1: `magit-log-buffer-file` (as per comment below)

Before magit 2.1: `magit-file-log` is what you are looking for. It will show you all commits for the file in the current buffer in the standard magit log view.

Comment: Since magit 2.1, `magit-file-log` was renamed to `magit-log-buffer-file`

Comment: Unfortunately, `magit-log-buffer-file` doesn't restrict the display of each commit to just that file.

Comment: @CatalinHritcu It works well at displaying all of the commits that affect that file, but it doesn't restrict the display of each commit to just that file.

Comment: The most convenient way I've found so far is to invoke `magit-log-buffer-file` and then run `magit-ediff-dwim` (bound to "e" shortcut in Spacemacs) on the commit of your choice. This will show a window with two panes with highlighted changes.

Comment: Unclear what @robin-green and @wilkystyle are describing, but perhaps the keystrokes `l`, `-u`, and `l` will help after `magit-log-buffer-file`

Comment: I guess none of the features support log for a file that isn't there any more?

Answer (score 45):

Open your `magit-status` buffer, by typing `M-x magit-status` (I used to have this bound to `C-. C-g` because it is used all the time. These days, I use Spacemacs so it's `<SPC> g s`)

1. Type `l` to get log viewing option
2. Type `--` to set the "Limit to files" option (used to be `=f`)
3. Enter the file path you wish to view history for
4. Type `l` to view the log of the current branch

If you're using Spacemacs, you can get the history of the currently visited file using `<SPC> g f h`

Comment: I think step 2 is now `--` (`Magit 20200112.2023, Git 2.20.1, Emacs 26.1, gnu/linux`)

Comment: Nice, works also with files that were deleted at some point.

Comment: is there an easy way to automatically enter the filename associated with the buffer you were visiting before you entered magit status? (in step 3)

Comment: @hraban the command `magit-log-buffer-file` is what you want. With Spacemacs you can use `<SPC> g f h`

Comment: @BryanAsh unfortunately I don't use Spacemacs. I added my own entry for it in the magit log transient: `(transient-append-suffix 'magit-log "l" '("f" "Current file" magit-log-buffer-file))`, access with `C-x M-g l f`.

Answer (score 12):

In your `*magit: <project>*` buffer use `l` to go into logging mode, then press `f` to be prompted for a filename.

Comment: This is no longer an option in the transient map, magit-20210303.1208 ... not sure when it changed, perhaps related to @Ragge's mention of "before/since magit-2.1".

Answer (score 5):

If [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) ([user manual](https://magit.vc/manual/)) doesn't have that feature, then you can have a look at other [Emacs mode](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=113313040724346), and add you own `git-log-file` function:

```
(defun git-log-file ()
  "Display a log of changes to the marked file(s)."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((files (git-marked-files))
         (buffer (apply #'git-run-command-buffer "*git-log*" "git-rev-list" \
"--pretty" "HEAD" "--" (git-get-filenames files))))  (with-current-buffer buffer
      ; (git-log-mode)  FIXME: implement log mode
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (setq buffer-read-only t))
    (display-buffer buffer)))
```

Comment: Or just use `C-x v l`

Comment: I am having following message: `Symbol’s function definition is void: git-marked-files`

Comment: @alp 7 years later, that issue would be better represented in its own question, with the exact version of the OS, eclipse and magic plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know a way. I simply use `M-x vc-print-log` which seems to accomplish the same feat. It is not a magit-integrated way, though.

Answer (score 3):

Hit <kbd>`C-c`</kbd><kbd>`M-g`</kbd> to bring up the `magit-file-dispatch`: it has several "file-local" magit commands, such as blame and log (<kbd>`l`</kbd>).