# How to find when a file was deleted in Magit

Tags: magit

[Find when a file was deleted in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839398/find-when-a-file-was-deleted-in-git) is the answer for git, but how to find when a file was deleted, in magit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "--" infix argument in the log transient. This lists commits which touch the given file name.

For example, to find when the file "src/main.c" was deleted, in the current branch, type:

```
l   ;; magit-log
--  ;; "Limit to files"
src/main.c RET
l   ;; current
```

There might be a default filename that you need to delete or edit (or accept).

Related: [View a file's history in Magit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352932)