# Git search a commit where a file has been modified

Tags: git

I have modified a file, and I do not know anymore when. I want to see all the commits where I have changed that file. And based on those commits I want to search for other modifications in other files that are linked to the modification I am searching for. I have tried `git blame` but it seems that is just showing the last commit and uncommitted changes. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

---

To be more explicit: I am searching modifications in a json file and based on those, I have done some modification in my application code (cpp) files. So I want to search those commits and see the code that I have modified. P.S.: I have changed the structure of the json meanwhile, so I do not want just the last modification.

Comment: `git log --follow -p file`

Comment: possible duplicate of [View the change history of a file using Git versioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To view what and how commits changed some file you can use `log` command with `-p` switch:

```
git log -p somefile/somefile.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the commits that affect a certain file with:

```
git log -- <filename>
```

If you want to see the other files that were modified along with that file, you can use the `--name-only` option.  This will list all the files that are modified in that commit.

```
git log --name-only <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out who changed a file, you can run git blame against a single file, and you get a breakdown of the file, line-by-line, with the change that last affected that line. It also prints out the timestamp and author information as well [link](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/07/git-tip-of-week-assigning-blame.html)

Answer (score 0):

In everyday work i find this the most convenient:

```
gitk <some file or directory>
```

It's nice to be able to quickly filter out all commits that changed the content of a certain directory, especially in a larger system. The fact that you can click the files to see the diffs instantly makes it, at least for, the fastest way to get an overview.