# How to view the changes in a single file in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

My last commit updated ~300 files, and the diff page says `Sorry, we could not display the entire diff because it was too big` and is so slow that I can barely scroll it. How can I see changes for a single file?

When viewing a specific file, I expected to have a link to compare it with the previous version, but I can't find any. Am I missing something or why isn't such an important feature there?

Comment: @riv - could you link to the source file? I don't have an example of that size on hand.

Comment: @mjb: https://github.com/d07RiV/d3planner/blob/master/scripts/bnet-parser.js

Answer (score 0):

Use git diff.  It can take revision and file arguments.

```
git diff master ./myawesomefile.txt
```

will show how master's version of the file differs from your local version

```
git diff 878a984e ./myawesomefile.txt
```

will show how commit hash 786876 differs from your current local version

```
git diff 878a984e 48d74774 ./myawesomefile.txt
```

will show how commit hash 878a984e version of myawesomefile.txt differs from 48d74774

Comment: In case git gets confused about which parameters are git refs and which are files, you get into the habit of adding `--` between the refs and the files.
`git diff 878a98ae -- acefile 432.txt`

Comment: not related to using github

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for [this cheatsheet](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/). You can compare across time like [this link](https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/master@%7B2015-02-27%7D...master) does with `master@%7B2015-02-27%7D...master` in the end or across commits for specific files [like this one](https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/96d29b7662f148842486d46117786ccb7fcc8018%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E...96d29b7662f148842486d46117786ccb7fcc8018) does with `^` after the base you want to compare.

I tend to do this all locally using `git fetch master && git diff ..master` to compare my current branch to an updated master, but you certainly can do this with the above.

Answer (score -1):

You can view the change history of a file by clicking on the history button, or by adding `commits` to the url of the file. Here is what it looks like for a file at the homebrew repo on github.

e.g.

```
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/SUPPORTERS.md
```

---

Or you can try:

On GitHub, there are, essentially, two different ways to see the commit history of a repository:

```
By navigating directly to the commits page of a repository.

By clicking on a file, then selecting History, to get to the commit history for a specific file.
```

For more information on how Git considers commit history, you can read up on the "History Simplification" section of the [git log][2] help article.

Comment: The last link points to an anchor in the full diff, which isn't very helpful in my case since my diff doesn't even list all the files.

Comment: @riv In that case, use "Blame" option, that is explicit in the first method: https://github.com/d07RiV/d3planner/blame/master/scripts/bnet-parser.js

Comment: or replace in your url with the specific id commit: https://github.com/d07RiV/d3planner/commit/dbcce5c5648ea7aa1d1c6c065dc3348e50501101 [link](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/)

Comment: Yeah I tried Blame but its not as good as a proper diff since it doesn't show the original contents.

Comment: @riv .... well riv, I have two more option, I hope and it can help you. 1.- Install GitHub por PC [link](https://windows.github.com/), login with you credentials and to this [link](http://www.amaslo.com/2012/09/how-to-avoid-github-clients-diff-is-too.html) or 2.- Install Git for Windows [link](https://msysgit.github.io/), and use the line command `gitk [filename]` as appear here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning). If I find other solution I'll share with you as soon as possible.

Comment: I couldn't find another way. Sorry Riv.

Comment: Thanks for the github history tipp! Awesome:)