# How can I blame a deleted file in Git?

Tags: git

Git blame helps when investigating why code in a file is a certain way. [git gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) is even better in that it allows you to step backwards in time to see the context of the file when code was added.

However, `git blame <file>` and `git gui blame <file>` do not work after a file has been deleted. An error will appear as:

```
fatal: cannot stat path 'file': No such file or directory
```

How does one blame a deleted file?

Comment: Instead of `git blame`, it may be easier to use `git log -p` as indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/278242/1015595

Answer (score 51):

### git blame

`git blame` works when providing a commit reference that contains the file. Find the most recent one with log:

```
$ git log -2 --oneline -- example/path/file.txt

 fffffff deleting file.txt
 eeeeeee Last change to file.txt before deleting.
```

Then blame the parent commit:

```
$ git blame eeeeeee -- example/path/file.txt
```

### git gui blame

`git gui blame` won't work this way, however. A work around is to browse the repository at the last commit that contained the file, then from the GUI select the file and launch the blame viewer:

```
$ git gui blame eeeeeee example/path/file.txt
```

---

(Note: Use `log -2` and `eeeeeee` instead of `fffffff^` because `git gui blame` can not handle `fffffff^:example/path/file.txt`)