# browse git commit history for a single file in a GUI

Tags: git, github, version-control

Edit: Not cool to site command line questions and mark as duplicate when this question was specifically concerning GUI solutions. Original question below.

I'm looking for a GUI that can help me view the commit history for a single file in a git repo. Something roughly equivalent to `git log --follow filename` but with more features.

Does there exist a software GUI for this purpose? Like a diff viewer with a forward/back button to explore the history of a file? I'm currently using GitHub.com code history section for this, but it's not super convenient and requires opening links then going back to the previous page to find the next/previous commit for a file.

Comment: Is it answered  [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning)

Comment: [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17955109/2047843) in the question posted by @AlexanderDmitriev explains how to do this with SourceTree, which is what I use.

Comment: I have found that just using `git log`, in conjunction with a good Git IDE plugin (e.g. IntelliJ), works just fine for me.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question, people. This question is about GUI solutions. Yes, the answer is Sourcetree, but none of the questions linked here were concerning GUI for exploring diff history for a single file (very specific question).

Answer (score 3):

You can open `gitk` and pass a single file as a parameter.

```
gitk somefile.cc
```

This will open the `gitk` gui and you will be able to click all commits where the file was updated and see the diff vs previous commit.