# Find out how git is handling a specific file?

Tags: git, file, status

I'm working in a repository that I'm unfamiliar with, and I need to better understand how git is treating various files. Any given file could be one or more of the following:

- Tracked, and up-to-date
- Tracked, with working tree changes
- Tracked, with staged changes
- Staged added
- Untracked
- Ignored by .gitignore or some other mechanism
- Marked assumed-unchanged
- Missing

Is there some sort of `git info <fileName>` command that will tell me everything git knows about that file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View the change history of a file using Git versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning)

Comment: `git status <filename>`

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon `git status <filename>` silently ignores ignored files. `git status --ignored <filename>` shows info about ignored files, but seems to silently ignore everything else.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin `git log <filename>` silently ignores ignored and added files, and gives me far too much info for tracked files.

Comment: You could also have a file that is tracked, with staged changes and with working tree changes... but i think the closest you can get to what you are asking is using `git status --short`

Comment: @jthill ... unless I cloned and modified it myself a while ago, and am just now returning to the work... not that I would ever do that...

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

Basically, `git status` is Git's best attempt to tell you everything at once.

If a file isn't showing up, and you think it might be ignored, `git check-ignore -v` is useful: it will tell you *why* the file is ignored, if it is ignored, or say nothing if it's not ignored.

There is one thing that's missing, which is a quick and easy way to see the special flags that you can set in the index.

`git ls-files` can show you what's in the index, but it's not very user friendly.

#### Long

In Git, *tracked* simply means *is present in the index*.  At the same time, only *untracked* files can be ignored.  An *untracked* file is, by definition, a file that is *not* in the index, but *is* in your work-tree—the area in which you do your everyday work.

The index is also perhaps best described as *what will go into the next commit*.  (It's more complicated than that—because the index has a few additional roles—but that's the short version.)  A new `git commit` simply packages up the files that are in the index to make the snapshot for the new commit.  Everything else flows from this.

Remember that at all times, there are, in effect, *three* active copies of a tracked file, though two of them can be missing:

- There is the `HEAD` (current commit) copy, which is where the file came from initially.  If there is no `HEAD` copy, the file is new: it will be an added file in the next commit, as compared to the current commit.

  The `HEAD` copy of the file, like any committed copy of any file, is read-only.  Nothing you can do can change it.  It's in a special Git-only format and is quite tricky to find: you have to have Git *extract* it into a usable form.
- There is the index copy.  Technically this is really a reference to a copy somewhere else.  It too is in the special internal Git format for files (a "blob object", in Git terms) but for your own purposes you can just think of it as a whole separate physical copy, because you can, at any time, *overwrite* it with a *new* copy, or remove it.
- Last, there is the work-tree copy.  This is the only version of the file that you can see with your ordinary computer tools.  It's in your computer's ordinary format, so you can do anything you like with this copy.

  If the work-tree copy of a tracked file is missing, it looks deleted, as compared to the (not-deleted) index copy.

When you first `git checkout` some commit—each commit is uniquely specified by its big ugly hash ID, so that you can check out old ones if you like—Git reads the commit's files into the index, so that all the committed files are there and no other files are there.<sup>1</sup>  So now `HEAD`, which is the commit you just checked out, and the index *match*.  Meanwhile, this same `git checkout` also removes from your work-tree all the *tracked* files from the commit you had out a moment ago, and replaces them with the files from the index that are from the new `HEAD` commit.  So now all the index copies match all the work-tree copies.  None of your *untracked* files are touched here, only the tracked ones.

The effect is that right after `git checkout`, *all three copies of every tracked file match*.  There's the unchangeable copy in the `HEAD` commit, which has been copied into the index, which has been copied into your work-tree.

From here on, you can:

- modify (or create or remove) a work-tree file however you like;
- use `git add` to copy a work-tree file *into* the index: now the two match, and if the file was not in the index at all before, now it is in the index;
- use `git rm` to *remove* a file from *both* the index *and* the work-tree: now it's gone from both;
- use (one form of) `git reset` to copy a file from the `HEAD` to the index without touching the work-tree; and/or
- use various other Git commands, such as `git rm --cached` or special forms of `git checkout` that are now easier in Git 2.23+ via the new `git restore`, to
  achieve other manipulations of the index and/or work-tree.

Whatever you do, the `HEAD` copy of the file never changes.  The index copy is either there, so that the file is tracked, or not there, so that the file is untracked.  The work-tree copy is there or not: Git does not really care, because Git will use the *index* copy for the next commit.

To see what's *different*, you must have Git compare:

- `HEAD` vs index: anything that is *the same* is boring; `git status` says nothing about that.  Anything that is *different* is interesting: `git status` tells you *staged for commit*, because if you ran `git commit` right now, the new commit you would make would be different from the current commit.
- index vs work-tree: anything that is *the same* is boring and `git status` says nothing.  Anything that is *different* is interesting: `git status` tells you *not staged for commit*, because you could update the index copy of the file (or remove it) to match the work-tree, after which it might not match the current commit any more.

Last—well, *almost* last—given any *untracked* file—which by definition isn't in the index—`git status` will complain about it being untracked, *unless* you use an "ignore" file to make it shut up.  The ones you make Git shut up about are your ignored files.

Note that a tracked file can be different in *all three* copies.  In this case, both of the two comparisons—`HEAD`-vs-index, and index-vs-work-tree—that `git status` runs, result in "interesting" results.  You will see the file as both *staged for commit* and *not staged for commit*.  Sometimes, the result of `git status --short`, which puts both results into the first two columns of output from one-line-per-file output with multiple columns, is useful here.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a slight oversimplification.  There is a lot of gory detail about when *uncommitted changes* can be carried across a checkout in [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

---

#### Assume-unchanged and skip-worktree

You mention the `--assume-unchanged` flag.  There is also a `--skip-worktree` flag.  These flags are slightly different internally, but for the most part, achieve the same result.  They can only be set on a file that *is* in the index, so they only apply to tracked files.  Also, only *you* (or some command you run) can set them: a new clone never has *any* of these flags set.

Their effect is to tell Git—especially `git status`, which is doing a *lot* of file comparing—that it should *not bother to look at* the work-tree copy of the file.  Instead, when Git would have checked the work-tree copy, Git can just *assume* that the work-tree copy matches the index copy.

These flags are a little bit hard to view, because they're stored in the index, which itself is a little bit hard to view.  The `git ls-files` command can show them, along with all the entries in the index—which tends to be thousands of lines in many projects, and hence not all that useful in practice.  I wrote a little [Python script that I call `git-flagged`](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged) so that I can run `git flagged` to see which files have these flags set, and/or reset the flags, without seeing a lot of other irrelevant stuff.<sup>2</sup>

Note that operations like `git checkout` and `git merge` will look past these flags and warn you if a work-tree file would be overwritten.  That is, you might make some local change to some file, flag the index copy so that Git normally stops showing you *changes not staged for commit*, and work for a while, including making new commits, which of course use the *index* copy of the file so they keep matching the previous commit.  But then, having done this for a while, you *forget* you have these local changes you're deliberately hiding.

At some point, someone else, in some other Git repository from which you regularly obtain commits, *changes the file*.  If you `git checkout` their commit, or `git merge` with their commit, Git would have to write *their* version of the file into your work-tree.  Fortunately, Git doesn't just do that without warning.  Unfortunately, you may have forgotten that you had flagged some files, and you might want to get a full list of all flagged files.

---

<sup>2</sup>You can also use `grep` or similar, but when I am using the flags a lot, it's nice to have something more convenient.