# Different dates of change from 1 file

Tags: git

With command `git diff toto.txt`, I can see all the code changes since the last commit.

Is it possible to have all dates of code changes?

For example:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

Day 1 toto.txt becomes:

```
aa
bbdd
cc
```

Day 2:

```
aazz
bbdd
cc
```

I would like a list of changes for toto.txt with date:

- aa -> aazz day 2
- bb -> bbdd day 1

git blame toto.txt|grep '0000000 (Not'
=>    00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2023-07-25 13:15:47 +0200  20) #    @svglog = Logger.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/mouchard_rsf.log", 5, 610440)
00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2023-07-25 13:15:47 +0200  21) #    @svglog.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
is more interesting, but for Not Committed the date is the command date not the change date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View the change history of a file using Git versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning)

Comment: You should add more infos if you want an helpful answer (i.e. you must explain that you want date of changes not yet in a commit)

Comment: Before create a commit, git diff toto.txt gives all changes. I would have dates of the changes. git log gives informations in relation to a commit so it is bad for me

Comment: Do you mean to get the date when *the file change on disk* **before** it was committed? If so, you're out of luck: git doesn't store that. The only "modification date" you can get from a change in a commit is the date of the commit itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the following command would provide the information you are looking for:

```
git log --patch toto.txt
```

This information was found in a similar question: [View the change history of a file using Git versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning).

Comment: fatal: unrecognized argument: --patch. git log is from commit. I want date of changes not yet in a commit ( before a commit)

Comment: git --version
git version 1.6.0.6